# How to play videos gotten from Mediastore using Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, mediastore, exoplayer2.x

I've seen how to use Exoplayer for streaming videos online but how do I use Exoplayer to play local videos gotten form the Mediastore?
Please, I just need a proper code sample to get started. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen https://exoplayer.dev/hello-world.html? 
It provides step-by-step instructions on how to set up an ExoPlayer to play a video given a URI.

To get a URI from a `Cursor` you get when querying Media Store, just use `.getData()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).